# How to implement cross realm single sign on in Keycloak?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

There is a use case where both application has different login credentials and need to implement single sign on.

It will have application based realm then how to implement cross realm solution in keycloak ?

Keycloak documentation

Comment: What is the purpose of having different realms per application?

Comment: @sventorben- we have two application where have different login credentials but want to enable SSO b/w both the application.

Comment: Do you want SSO across both applications?